# Highlighting text using Html.fromHtml

Tags: android, html

I am trying to add background color for the string inside MultiAutoCompleteTextView.

I am overriding replaceText method in multipleAutocompletetextview, trying to replace charactersequence with html like this

```
@Override
protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String styledText = "<font color='red'>"+text+"</font>.";
    super.replaceText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
}
```

this is working fine. I Can change the font color. But i want to add background color for the font. Can anybody suggest me, how to achieve this?

( The way we are adding tags while creating question, samething i am trying to implement using MultiAutoCompleteTextView. I want to add background for the selected string. )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`Html.fromHtml` does not support setting the background color.

You will either have to take the SpannedString returned by Html.fromHtml and set the `BackgroundColorSpan` to the text you want to set the background color of.

Something like:

```
new SpannableString(styledText).setSpan(
    new BackgroundColorSpan( Color.YELLOW), 0, styledText.length(),
      Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

See also: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html

You can as well pass your own TagHandler into `Html.fromHtml(String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)` to support additional HTML tags. 
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html

Answer (score 1):

Use SpannableString and BackgroundColorSpan available in android.